# Integral curves associated to the movement of a pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

The equation of a pendulum is given by $\ddot{\theta}=-\sin(\theta)$ so we write this as a system
$$\begin{cases} \theta'=\dot\theta\\
(\dot\theta)'=\ddot\theta=-\sin(\theta)\end{cases}$$
The vector field associated to this system is $\vec{F}(\theta,\dot\theta)=(\dot\theta,-\sin\theta)$
and the integral curves are given by $$\dot\theta^2=2\cos(\theta)+c\;\;\;\; (*)$$ I want to understand how to obtain the last equation $(*)$.

My undestanding is that if we have a curve $\gamma(t)=(\theta(t),\dot\theta(t))$ then we need the vector $\gamma'(t)$ to be colinear to the vector field $\vec{F}(\theta,\dot\theta)=(\dot\theta,-\sin\theta)$ but I can't see how write this into equations that lead to $(*)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the first equation by $\dot \theta$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\dot \theta \ddot \theta & = -\dot \theta \sin \theta \\
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \dot \theta^2 & = \frac{d}{dt} \cos \theta \\
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{1}{2} \dot \theta^2 - \cos \theta \right) & = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}\dot \theta^2 - \cos \theta & = E,
\end{align}
where $E$ is a constant of integration.